# how to return value from for loop each time

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What I want to do is when I press on right key from keyboard return 100 and when I press again return 200 then 300 and so on...

```
function looptest() {
    for (i = 100; i < 1000; i+=100) {
       result+=i;
    }
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            // do something
            break;
        case 38: // up
            //do something
            break;
        case 39: // right
           console.log(looptest());
            break;
        case 40: // down
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

This is my code and it returns every time 100, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: What does responding to the keystroke have to do with "return(ing) a value from a for loop each time"?

Comment: I couldn't see any return statement from looptest function. Can you change it? Also to achieve the desired functionality, you should have state maintained in your code.

Comment: Your loop is wrong , it will not give results like 100,200,300..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do simply something like

```
var count= 100;

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            // do something
            break;
        case 38: // up
            //do something
            break;
        case 39: // right

            console.log(count)
          count=count+100;

            break;
        case 40: // down
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

or if you want to use `looptest()` then change your function like below

```
count=0;
function looptest() {
   count=count+100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign K=0 in global space

```
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            // do something
            break;
        case 38: // up
            //do something
            break;
        case 39: // right
           K+=100
            break;
        case 40: // down
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will add 100 to `i` everytime you press the right key of your keyboard.

```
var i = 0;

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            // do something
            break;
        case 38: // up
            //do something
            break;
        case 39: // right
            i = i+100;
            console.log(i);
            break;
        case 40: // down
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 0; 
   function looptest() {
        for (i = 100; i < 1000; i+=100) {
           result =(result + i);
        }
    }

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {

        switch (e.which) {
            case 37: // left
                // do something
                break;
            case 38: // up
                //do something
                break;
            case 39: // right
               console.log(looptest());
                break;
            case 40: // down
                //do something
                break;
            default:
                return; // exit this handler for other keys
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    });
```

declare result globally
and while adding it is concating so please add them inside ()

Comment: i have a doubt is it the looptest() will give 100 as result?